# Join two models in django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models with a unique key: EMAIL. For both of the models the field EMAIL is unique, but some of the emails of model A do not necessarily exist in model B. I would like to perform an inner join, but since I'm quite new to Django I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the Email model look like this

```
class Email(models.Model):
    """
    Email model.
    """
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "This email has already been registered."
        }
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Then create 2 models related to Email model by using ForeignKey.

Or you just need to save email by using EmailField for each model.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    """
    A model.
    """
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="Email",
        unique=True,
    )
    ...other fields
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you need to make a relation between table in order to apply any type of join

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
     email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
     model_b = models.ForeignKey(to=ModelB, null=True, blank=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
     email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

then

```
data = ModelA.objects.filter(model_b__isnull=False)
```

Instance with same email id should be linked with each other.